# Dynamically removing the last border-right

Tags: jquery, slider, border

I used this slider but there is a detail which doesn't fit my desires.

The thing is that I would like the last border-right not to be shown but when I move into the slider I'd like to have it updated so I only get the most right border not shown.

I mean, e.g. this is the first slide: `a|b|c|d|` and I'd like to have `a|b|c|d`, Then when I click on the right arrow I would like to get `b|c|d|a` (without the last border "|").

I hope I explained well what I actually mean :)

http://jsfiddle.net/5AdgA/1/

Comment: Thank you everyone, especially to Yury and Rahul. I used the jquery function implemented by Rahul and I added the CSS rule of Yury to my page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#box ul li:last-of-type{
    border-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Both `first-child` and `last-child` are more widely supported.

Comment: @amustill: Could you plz specify any major browser supporting last-child but not last-of-type?

Comment: Thanks I used your solution together with rahul's solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

These are your elements

```
 <ul id="box_ul">
   <li><a href="#">a</li>
   <li><a href="#">b</li>
   <li><a href="#">c</li>
   <li><a href="#">d</li>
</ul>
```

In order to remove border from the last element you can simply use css as below:

## box_ul li:last-child { border-right: 0 }

Just make sure you place this line(css rule) after: #box ul li{} this style rule

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arzKJ/) to show a method of it working.

Essentially, each update, it adds the `last-child` class to the :last li. The reason it does this in jQuery and not using CSS psuedo-selectors is purely for browser support. If you need to support browsers like IE 6/7/8 then this is the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Switch your `border-right` to a `border-left` and then just `:first-child`. You could use `last-child`, but `first-child` is supported in IE8 as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/amustill/5AdgA/6/

Comment: I tried it, but I don't know why some times it works (if I start cliking the left arrow) and some times it doesn't (for example if I click the right arrow more than 2 times). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box_ul li:first').before($('#box_ul li:last')); 
    $('#box_ul li').css('border-right','1px solid #d5d5d5');
    $('#box_ul li:last').css('border-right','none');
   $('#right_scroll_clienti').click(function(){
       var item_width = $('#box_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;
       var left_indent = parseInt($('#box_ul').css('left')) - item_width;
       $('#box_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent},500,function(){    
            $('#box_ul li:last').after($('#box_ul li:first')); 
            $('#box_ul').css({'left' : '0px'});
           $('#box_ul li').css('border-right','1px solid #d5d5d5');
    $('#box_ul li:last').css('border-right','none');
       }); 

   });
   $('#left_scroll_clienti').click(function(){
       var item_width = $('#box_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;
       var left_indent = parseInt($('#box_ul').css('left')) + item_width;
       $('#box_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent},500,function(){    
            $('#box_ul li:first').before($('#box_ul li:last')); 
            $('#box_ul').css({'left' : '0px'});
           $('#box_ul li').css('border-right','1px solid #d5d5d5');
    $('#box_ul li:last').css('border-right','none');
       });
    });
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5AdgA/7/)

Comment: Thanks I used your solution together with Yury Tarabanko's solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

check this if this satisfy your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/5AdgA/9/

i just changed some css properties and added one div for the ul

```
  .slidewrapper{width:935px; overflow:hidden;} //added on css class for the slider and some little changes, not much.
```